# Google sheets - find the cell containing specific text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, using formulae, is there a way I can search for a certain string in a certain sheet, and return the reference of the cell which contains that string?

The string would be unique to that cell, but the data isn't stored in a list, nor is it sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `FIND` or `SEARCH` (which is case insensitive) into `LARGE` and `ARRAYFORMULA` functions:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G1,A1:F15))*ROW(A1:F15),1),LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G1,A1:F15))*COLUMN(A1:F15),1)))
```

[image]

If search string is not unique in range, it will find last cell that contains string. If you want find first cell, change `LARGE` to `SMALL` function.