# Google sheets - return the column number of a cell containing specific text

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, match, vlookup

In **Google Sheets**, using formulae, is there a way I can return the column number of a cell that equals a specific string?

I often use the `VLOOKUP` formula, but find that I update and add columns in the target sheet over time. The result is that any `VLOOKUP` pointing at that sheet will return incorrect results because the index of the value to be returned is no longer correct.

So I'm looking for a formula I can use to return the index number in a `VLOOKUP` formula, which will always find the column index based on the title text of that column, e.g. "Email".

The formula would need to return the index of the cell that equals, not just contains, the search text, ie return the index of "Email" column, not the "Manager Email" column. The column titles will always be unique.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752655/google-sheets-find-the-cell-containing-specific-text), but this returns the the whole cell reference, not just the index - I'm hoping there's a simpler solution to return just the column index by searching a single row (the first row) of a sheet for a cell containing the search text.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. The most efficient way to share that technique with you is if you will share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet containing at least enough realistic data in the right places to illustrate the problem you're trying to solve. It will help if the sheets are named the same as your real-world sheet. Any sensitive data can be replaced with unique and realistic dummy data. And the only need contain five or ten rows of data.

Comment: Use  `MATCH()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use:

```
=MATCH("Email"; 1:1; 0)
```

match string in row 1 if exact match

also note that if you use this in Sheet2 you will need to use `Sheet1!1:1`

Comment: Hi @player0. What if I want multiple column indexes to returned if I have multiple columns displaying "Email"? I was trying with this but it only displays the first search (1st from left) and leaves out the other ones to the right. I can make this a question if it's not simple. Thanks

Comment: @Verminous can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: @player0 Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x-IkvUr8hEoBwkKaoZWfdITSf4WXwFCgROpIEwOkaOI/edit The reason why I am interested in this is because I needed a way to get ```QUERY```  +  ```asc``` and ```desc``` to sort multiple colmns. For example in that Sheet if I click on "Speed" with descending there are a lot of objects with 9 speed. I'd like a way to sort for situations with same value, like 9, to then choose a 2nd sort option like click on Strength and then Within objects with 9 then also sort with Strength, if I click Strength, I could click something else like Fire.

Comment: @player0 the sort code with ```QUERY``` is on ```Q4``` Let me know if you want this as a question.

Comment: @Verminous if you post it as a question we both will get some rep points out of it... anyway, in your row 2 you got some checkboxes... did I understand it correctly that those are for sorting? like if checked then sort. is that the case?

Comment: Hey @player0 they are for sorting yes. It's the best I could come up with for sorting columns fast and simple. I wanted to also make it so that if I check 2 columns the QUERY formula would sort 2 columns like ```SORT Col1 asc, Col2 asc```. So for ex. within a sort of same value like 9 speed, the 2nd choosen column would sort within the universe of 9 speed. I can't explain better. So that is why I was playing around with ```MATCH``` and ```ADDRESS``` etc. Ok I will start building the question now and will let you know the URL for the question here as comment.

Comment: There is also the problem of positioning. If I want to 1st sort SPEED and then  within 9 SPEED sort by GENDER in order to see FEMALES with 9 SPEED first then 9 SPEED MALES it would not work because the column SPEED is to the right of GENDER column. It seems like the position matters because formulas read from left to right.

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72904569/how-to-sort-multiple-columns-using-query-function-together-with-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try `MATCH()` function within `INDEX()` like.

```
=INDEX(D3:G5,2,MATCH("Email",D2:G2,0))
```

[image]